# Adding new row to jqGrid using modal form on client only

Tags: jqgrid, local, editing, form-editing

There appear to be many solutions that are very close to addressing my problem but of the dozens and dozens of questions I've poured through not one seems to exactly address what I'm trying to do. Although I have seen nearly the same question asked without an answer. I have tried so many combinations of options and functions to no avail.

I want to use the modal form to add a new row with the inputted values to the jqGrid but I do not want it to post to the server upon Submit. I do want to eventually post to the server but only after the client user has performed additional editing (if needed) on the row(s) added from the modal form. I do not want any rows saved to the remote database until the client has performed some edits which in turn dynamically update other columns. Once a certain status of values are validated then a Save button is displayed and the Grid row(s) can be posted to the server. Unless this validated condition is met the row(s) are not to be submitted to the database. I have a number of jqGrids in use elsewhere in my app which do post the new row data of a submitted modal form but this grid I'm trying to accomplish something different with the client which doesn't immediately involve the server. I like the more intuitive interface of the modal form for the initial entry of values with the client user then editing inline the fields of the new row if needed which is what has necessitated my question: can I submit the form as a new row only without  any posting action to the server occurring?

I saw in the jqGrid Wiki resource a comment made by a user who said if "clientArray" is the value entered for use the Grids modal form submission option "editurl: "clientArray" that the modal form would not spit the "No URL is set" message but it still does and a new row is not added to the grid. I've made the Grid datatype as a local "datatype: 'clientSide'" but get the same "No URL is set" error message. The script is pretty straightforward for the modal form which is invoked by a custom button as follows:

(The "footerrow, userDataOnFooter and altRows" options are included as part of the values updating in a summary footer which is related to editing performed upon the cells of the new row(s) being added through the modal form)

```
jQuery("#grid_test").jqGrid({
    url:'/grid_test_url.asp?id=' + vId,
    datatype: "clientSide",
    colNames: ['ID','Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3','Col 4'],
    colModel: [

        {name:'id',index:'id',width:90,align:"center",editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}, formoptions: {...}, editrules: {...}},
        {name:'col1',index:'col1',width:130,align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}, formoptions: {}, editrules: {}},
        {name:'col2',index:'col2',width:130,align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size: 25}, formoptions: {}, editrules: {}},
        {name:'col3',index:'col3',width:130,align:"right",editable: true,editoptions:{size:25}, formoptions: {}, editrules: {}},
        {name:'col4',index:'col4',width:130,align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{ size: 25 }, formoptions: {}, editrules: {}}   

    ],
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[5,10,20],
    pager: '#pgrid_test',
    toolbar: [true, "top"],
    editurl: '', //not sure what would go here to block attempted post by the Submit action of the modal form
    width: 500,
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    multiselect: true,
    cellEdit: true,
    caption: "Grid Test Add New Row",
    footerrow: true, 
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    altRows: true
})
jQuery("#grid_test").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pgrid_test', { add: false, edit: false, del: false })

//append custom button
$("#t_grid_test").append("<input type='button' class='add' value='Add New Row' style='height:20px; color:green; font-size:11px;' />");

$("input.add", "#t_grid_test").click(function () {
    jQuery("#grid_test").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {
        jqModal: true,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        navkeys: [true, 38, 40],
        bottominfo: "Fields marked with (*) are required. ",
        addCaption: 'New Row Values',
        width: 300,
        dataheight: 200,
        recreateForm: true,

      //checkOnUpdate: true,
      //checkOnSubmit: true,
      //reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true
        //clearAfterAdd: true
    })
});
```

I hope this is reasonably clear. It seems it should be rather simple to add a row using the modal form without it immediately posting to the server but I cannot work out the solution. And please bear with if I don't promptly click the icons for the proper credit given for answers but I will when I know what to click so please advise accordingly. :)
Many thanks in advance.
Jerry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current version of the form editing don't support local datatype. Nevertheless one can do implement if with a little more long code. I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm) some time ago and posted [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-bug-in-generating-new-id-in-postit-of-editgridrow/#p22393) the suggestion to implement the local editing support in jqGrid. Till now it is not yet implemented, but you can use my example to implement what you need.

I include the code below:

```js
var lastSel, mydata = [
        {id:"1", invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",  note:"note",  amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",closed:true, ship_via:"TN",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2", invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2", note:"note2", amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",closed:false,ship_via:"FE",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3", invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3", note:"note3", amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",closed:false,ship_via:"FE",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4", invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test4", note:"note4", amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",closed:true ,ship_via:"TN",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"5", invdate:"2007-10-31",name:"test5", note:"note5", amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",closed:false,ship_via:"FE",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"6", invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test6", note:"note6", amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",closed:false,ship_via:"FE",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"7", invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test7", note:"note7", amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",closed:true ,ship_via:"TN",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"8", invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test8", note:"note8", amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",closed:false,ship_via:"FE",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"9", invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test9", note:"note9", amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",closed:false,ship_via:"TN",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"10",invdate:"2007-09-08",name:"test10",note:"note10",amount:"500.00",tax:"30.00",closed:true ,ship_via:"TN",total:"530.00"},
        {id:"11",invdate:"2007-09-08",name:"test11",note:"note11",amount:"500.00",tax:"30.00",closed:false,ship_via:"FE",total:"530.00"},
        {id:"12",invdate:"2007-09-10",name:"test12",note:"note12",amount:"500.00",tax:"30.00",closed:false,ship_via:"FE",total:"530.00"}
    ],
    grid = $("#list"),
    onclickSubmitLocal = function(options,postdata) {
        var grid_p = grid[0].p,
            idname = grid_p.prmNames.id,
            grid_id = grid[0].id,
            id_in_postdata = grid_id+"_id",
            rowid = postdata[id_in_postdata],
            addMode = rowid === "_empty",
            oldValueOfSortColumn;

        // postdata has row id property with another name. we fix it:
        if (addMode) {
            // generate new id
            var new_id = grid_p.records + 1;
            while ($("#"+new_id).length !== 0) {
                new_id++;
            }
            postdata[idname] = String(new_id);
        } else if (typeof(postdata[idname]) === "undefined") {
            // set id property only if the property not exist
            postdata[idname] = rowid;
        }
        delete postdata[id_in_postdata];

        // prepare postdata for tree grid
        if(grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
            if(addMode) {
                var tr_par_id = grid_p.treeGridModel === 'adjacency' ? grid_p.treeReader.parent_id_field : 'parent_id';
                postdata[tr_par_id] = grid_p.selrow;
            }

            $.each(grid_p.treeReader, function (i){
                if(postdata.hasOwnProperty(this)) {
                    delete postdata[this];
                }
            });
        }

        // decode data if there encoded with autoencode
        if(grid_p.autoencode) {
            $.each(postdata,function(n,v){
                postdata[n] = $.jgrid.htmlDecode(v); // TODO: some columns could be skipped
            });
        }

        // save old value from the sorted column
        oldValueOfSortColumn = grid_p.sortname === "" ? undefined: grid.jqGrid('getCell',rowid,grid_p.sortname);

        // save the data in the grid
        if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
            if (addMode) {
                grid.jqGrid("addChildNode",rowid,grid_p.selrow,postdata);
            } else {
                grid.jqGrid("setTreeRow",rowid,postdata);
            }
        } else {
            if (addMode) {
                grid.jqGrid("addRowData",rowid,postdata,options.addedrow);
            } else {
                grid.jqGrid("setRowData",rowid,postdata);
            }
        }

        if ((addMode && options.closeAfterAdd) || (!addMode && options.closeAfterEdit)) {
            // close the edit/add dialog
            $.jgrid.hideModal("#editmod"+grid_id,
                              {gb:"#gbox_"+grid_id,jqm:options.jqModal,onClose:options.onClose});
        }

        if (postdata[grid_p.sortname] !== oldValueOfSortColumn) {
            // if the data are changed in the column by which are currently sorted
            // we need resort the grid
            setTimeout(function() {
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
            },100);
        }

        // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
        this.processing = true;
        return {};
    },
    editSettings = {
        //recreateForm:true,
        jqModal:false,
        reloadAfterSubmit:false,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        savekey: [true,13],
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        onclickSubmit:onclickSubmitLocal
    },
    addSettings = {
        //recreateForm:true,
        jqModal:false,
        reloadAfterSubmit:false,
        savekey: [true,13],
        closeOnEscape:true,
        closeAfterAdd:true,
        onclickSubmit:onclickSubmitLocal
    },
    delSettings = {
        // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes to the server
        // so I use "processing:true" setting and delete the row manually in onclickSubmit
        onclickSubmit: function(options) { //, rowid) {
            var grid_id = grid[0].id,
                grid_p = grid[0].p,
                newPage = grid_p.page,
                rowids = grid_p.multiselect? grid_p.selarrrow: [grid_p.selrow];

            // reset the value of processing option to true
            // because the value can be changed by jqGrid
            options.processing = true;

            // delete selected row/rows (multiselect:true)
            $.each(rowids, function () {
                grid.delRowData(this);
            });
            // delete the row
            //grid.delRowData(rowid);
            $.jgrid.hideModal("#delmod"+grid_id,
                              {gb:"#gbox_"+grid_id,jqm:options.jqModal,onClose:options.onClose});

            if (grid_p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
                if (grid_p.reccount === 0 && newPage === grid_p.lastpage) {
                    // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
                    // which is the last page of the grid
                    newPage--; // go to the previous page
                }
                // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:newPage}]);
            }

            return true;
        },
        processing:true
    },
    initDateEdit = function(elem) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                autoSize: true,
                showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
            //$(elem).focus();
     },100);
    },
    initDateSearch = function(elem) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                autoSize: true,
                //showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
            //$(elem).focus();
     },100);
    };

grid.jqGrid({
    datatype:'local',
    data: mydata,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date','Client','Amount','Tax','Total','Closed','Shipped via','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id',width:70,align:'center',sorttype: 'int',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']}},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate',width:80, align:'center', sorttype:'date',
         formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'d-M-Y'}, editable:true, datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
         editoptions: {dataInit:initDateEdit},
         searchoptions: {dataInit:initDateSearch}},
        {name:'name',index:'name',editable: true, width:70, editrules:{required:true}},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount',width:100, formatter:'number', editable: true, align:'right'},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax',width:70, formatter:'number', editable: true, align:'right'},
        {name:'total',index:'total',width:120, formatter:'number', editable: true, align:'right'},
        {name:'closed',index:'closed',width:110,align:'center',editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox',
         edittype:'checkbox',editoptions:{value:'Yes:No',defaultValue:'Yes'},
         stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt:['eq','ne'], value:':All;true:Yes;false:No' }},
        {name:'ship_via',index:'ship_via',width:120,align:'center',editable: true, formatter:'select',
         edittype:'select',editoptions:{value:'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim', defaultValue:'Intime'},
         stype:'select', searchoptions:{value:':All;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim'}},
        {name:'note',index:'note',width:100,sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:'textarea'}
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[5,10,20],
    pager: '#pager',
    gridview:true,
    rownumbers:true,
    autoencode:true,
    ignoreCase:true,
    sortname: 'invdate',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    caption:'How to implement local form editing',
    height: '100%',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid, ri, ci) {
        var p = grid[0].p;
        if (p.selrow !== rowid) {
            // prevent the row from be unselected on double-click
            // the implementation is for "multiselect:false" which we use,
            // but one can easy modify the code for "multiselect:true"
            grid.jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
        }
        grid.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, editSettings);
    },
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSel) {
            // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
            // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
            // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
            // if jqGrid not in editing state
            if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                grid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
            }
            lastSel = id;
        }
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{},editSettings,addSettings,delSettings,
          {multipleSearch:true,overlay:false,
           onClose:function(form){
               // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
               // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
               // the div used by datepicker
               $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
           }});
```

**UPDATED**: The code change to work with jqGrid 4.4.1 I posted in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296186/315935).

**UPDATED 2**: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847745/315935) provide update for 4.5.4.

**UPDATED 3**: New 4.7 version of jqGrid supports now form editing of local data. The corresponding demo which uses the new version is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing47.htm). I need just add new `reformatAfterEdit: true` option of `formatter: "date"`. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing2_.htm) uses jqGrid 4.6.

Comment: @Oleg - Exactly what I needed. Unfortunately, it appears to no longer work with jqGrid 4.6 or 4.7. The form doesn't reset and then  errors on "Client required" even if there's data in the form,

Comment: @MSquared: What should one do exactly to reproduce the problem? (row editing, add new row or delete a row). I tried [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing2_.htm) where I just replaced jqGrid and I could reproduce any problems. I used the demo referenced in **UPDATED 2** as the template.

Comment: @MSquared: see **UPDATED 3** part of my answer.

Comment: Brilliant ! well concerned.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 
as `4.3.2` there is a change in behavior of the Grid

with `4.3.1`

```
onclickSubmitLocal = function(options,postdata) {
....
        // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
        this.processing = true;
        return {};
```

with `4.3.2`

```
onclickSubmitLocal = function(options,postdata) {
....
        // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
        options.processing = true;
        return {};
```

otherwise the grid return the url error