# jqGrid edit record form empty

Tags: jqgrid

I've implemented a jqGrid, but when I try to use the built-in form edit feature, an empty form pops up.

For every column i have set editable:true except for the table's primary key, an auto-incremented id. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to have a valid editurl, rather than clientArray? Below is the jqGrid implementation:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: colUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(result){
        result = jQuery.parseJSON( result )
        var colN = result.colNames;
        var colM = result.colModelList;
        $("#jqTable").jqGrid({
            url:dataUrl,
            datatype: 'xml',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:colN,
            colModel:colM,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            caption: db + "." + table,
            pager: '#jqPager',
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            sortname: 'dbid',
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 1000,
            height: 400
          });
        $("#jqTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqPager',
            {edit:true, add:false, del:false, search:true, view:false}, //options
            {}, // edit options
            {}, // add options
            {}, // del options
            {multipleSearch:true,
             sopt : ['eq',//equals
                 'ne',//not equals
                 'lt',//less than
                 'le',//less than or equal
                 'gt',//greater than
                 'ge',//greater than or equal
                 'bw',//begins with
                 'bn',//does not begin with
                 'in',//in
                 'ni',//not in
                 'ew',//ends with
                 'en',//does not end with
                 'cn',//contains
                 'nc']//does not contain
            }, // search options
            {} //view options
        ); 
    },
    error: function(x,e){
        alert(x.readyState + " " + x.status + " " + e.msg);
    }
});
```

and here is sample colModel and ColName string:

```
"colModelList": [{"name":"dbid","index":"dbid","editable":"false"},{"name":"description","index":"description","editable":"true"},{"name":"file_name","index":"file_name","editable":"true"}],"colNames": ["dbid","description","file_name"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that the reason is because you use `"editable": "true"` or `"editable": "false"` instead of `"editable": true` or `"editable": false`.

Moreover you try to use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) for the **local data editing**. The current jqGrid implementation support local data editing only for [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) and [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing). If you do need to use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) to edit local data you can find [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm) in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611065/adding-new-row-to-jqgrid-using-modal-form-on-client-only/5611519#5611519). The code will be longer, but it is do possible to implement this.

Comment: Changed "editable":"true" to "editable":true and the form becomes populated. Awesome!

Comment: @Andrea: On [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/) you can find that the boolean data type should be encoded without double quotes.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest things... I was rewriting the control flow of my application and had set a default to all editable items as `false` and couldn't figure out what was happening.  Found my bug and fixed it, thanks :)