# How to construct Dynamic Dependent Combo series in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I have two combos in my jqGrid. One has the listing of Countries and the other has the listing of states of that country. I want a system where when I change the Countries combo the corresponding value of that Country's State will construct the second combo.

Is a detailed example available?

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495172/customizing-the-add-edit-dialog-in-jqgrid/6499309#6499309) or at [the another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects3.htm) from [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184). I hope it's want you need.

Comment: @Oleg thanks a lot. This is my Answer.

Comment: You are welcome! You can use voting of helpful answers by the way. The answers with higher voting will be easy found by other people. Voting of comments help not for searching.

Comment: @Oleg How can I vote on your answer where you just comment. Please make an answer and let me vote on that answer.

Comment: I mean the *original* answers which I referenced and which you could not found yourself. The problem is not my reputation which I can't use in any way. The voting is the most important searching criteria. The questions with low voting will be almost no time be found.

Comment: I will remember your suggestion. voting the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks for Oleg and to help others who are searching the same solution, the solution is as follows.

Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects.htm) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495172/customizing-the-add-edit-dialog-in-jqgrid/6499309#6499309), or at [the another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects3.htm) from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184).