# How can we fill a drop down list to cascade in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

How can we fill a drop down list to cascade in jqgrid??? example

I have a drop down list of countries and a drop down list of cities. How can  to Select a country in DropDownList Country Fill Only the cities in the City dropDownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499309/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935). I think it's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

use the countries' dropdown [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to capture the event of changing a country.
then, initialize your cities' dropdown to whatever is appropriate.