# Jqgrid filter not getting refreshed after selection

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

In my project jqgrid is implemented with drop down filter in top of Grid.
I want filter work Like Excel filter. 
Means When I select filter from one column then in next column filter should display only relevant data which is related to first selection.
Currently, it is showing whole data in next filter drop down. 
We have load data on loadcomplete event of jqgrid.

Comment: This is called a cascading drop down. I got this to work once using ASP.NET MVC. What are you using for your back end? What is providing the data? The first step is to build a URL that takes the parameter value as a parameter and returns a list of filtered entries. Have you done that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we fill a drop down list to cascade in jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015513/how-can-we-fill-a-drop-down-list-to-cascade-in-jqgrid)