# Jqgrid Edit Form Change Event of Select doesnt fire when scrolling thorugh records

Tags: jqgrid

I have been following this example, http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects2.htm, as it is just what I need. I have got it working but it doesnt work when scrolling through records. If you bring up the form and scroll from a UK record to a US record, the list doesnt change. The onChange event only fires when the user selects from the select drop down.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks for your help.

James

Comment: what you mean under "scrolling"? Do you use scroll button of the mouse or you mean the usage of the keyboard?

Comment: If you click edit selected row and then use the arrows to go to the next record, if you go from records 2 to 3 the country changes from UK to US but the State stays as Oxford. The change event doesnt seem to fire. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My old demo uses 'change' event handler defined in the `dataEvents` property of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). In the `dataEvents` array one can define other event handlers.

You need just bind `keyup` to the column exactly like it's described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935). In the body of the event handler you can do the same actions as in the body of the 'change' event handler (you can place the code in a function and call it from the both handlers). In the way you should be able to solve the problem.

**UPDATED:** I updated [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499309/315935) which was origin for the demo which you used. [The new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects1.htm) support the navigation buttons (the buttons to edit the 'next' or the 'previous' row) in the editing form.

Comment: OK. I will try it tomorrow. Im new to this so it might take me a while to figure out how to do what you said. Im assuming keyup will cover the clicking of the navigation arrows on the edit form? Doesnt sound right to me but I will try it! Thanks for your help, I think i will need all the help I can get! Thanks

Comment: @JC75: If you bind `keyup` to the column which has `edittype: 'select'` then only typing on the keys in the select element will be handled. So if the focus is on the `<select>` element and any key pressed the handle will be called.

Comment: Hi Oleg. But the keyup event only fires when i press a key. I may not be explaining myself well. If you look at your example again,  http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects2.htm, if you click on record 2 'Oscar Wilde' and then click the edit button to bring up the form. If you then click the arrow to go to Record 3 'Louise Fletcher', the Country changes but the State doesnt. WHich event fires when I got to the next record? Thanks again

Comment: @JC75: Sorry, but [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects2.htm) has no arrow in the Edit form. The problem dependent select is complex enough and the Next/Previous row are not really needed. So I prefer just use [viewPagerButtons: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) option to disable the buttons. Alternatively one have to write additional code for [onclickPgButtons](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) which reset the select.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for your help. I took your advice of disabling the navigation buttons. Worked perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: @JC75: You are welcome! I am working on modifying of my demo to support navigation buttons. I will inform you about after I finish the modification.

Comment: @JC75: The modified the demo. See "UPDATED" part of my answer.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Sorry but I am now having a problem that I am trying to get the function that fires on the change event to fire when the edit form first loads. So I can fill my second dropdown based on the first. I am using dataurl but the value of the first select drop down isnt available until after the form has loaded? Should I post another question? Thanks