# jqgrid setColProp not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using setColProp to dynamically load values into a `select` edittype.

I have the values successfully load whenever I call:

```
loadComplete: function() {
                $("#profile_table").setColProp('contract_num', { editoptions: { value: contract_list} });
            },
```

However it only works here, and only once. If I change the value of `contract_list` and try to update the jqgrid by calling

```
$("#profile_table").setColProp('contract_num', { editoptions: { value: contract_list} });
```

again from anywhere (from a button click, from afterSubmit, or even reloading table) it does nothing at all.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

**edit:
Here is a better explanation of what I'm trying to do.**

I have a jqGrid table with the id `#profile_table`.

This is part of the `colModel` in the jqGrid code:

```
colModel:[
                {name:'contract_num',index:'contract_num', editable: true, hidden: false, width:30, edittype: "select", editrules: {required: true}},   
]
```

Initially the `contract_num` edit field in the edit/add forms has no values in its `select` box. I load initial values from a javascript variable called `contract_list` that is created before the table gets created. I load these values initially by using:

```
loadComplete: function() {
                $("#profile_table").setColProp('contract_num', { editoptions: { value: contract_list} });
            },
```

This works fine, however it is possible that the values of `contract_list` will change whenever a user changes something else on the page that this table is displayed on. So I am trying to dynamically update the options inside of the `select` box for the `contract_num` field inside of the edit/add forms for this table. I successfully change the values inside of `contract_list`, however I cannot get the actual `select` box to update to the new values.

I am trying to update it by calling:

```
$("#profile_table").setColProp('contract_num', { editoptions: { value: contract_list} });
```

and then reloading the grid whenever someone changes the values for `contract_list`, however the table is not being updated.

Comment: It's important that you describe the problem more detailed. How the `editoptions.value` will be used? For example if you have some lines in *editing mode* the selects will not apdated automatically, but the next row which will start editing will use new settings. If you use `formatter: 'select'` together with `editoptions.value` you have to reload grig to apply the changes in the grid body. Could you include more full code example?

Comment: I added more code and a better explanation of what I am trying to do, I hope you can understand my problem now, thanks

Comment: Sorry, but the updated part don't clear anything. You wrote "I cannot get the actual select box to update to the new values". What is "actual select box". The select exist **only if one edits** some cell or row (I still don't know which editing mode you use). Why you reload the grid after `setColProp`? Do you had at the moment some row in editing mode? If the answer is "no row" that you don't need to do any reloading. Why you placed `setColProp` inside of `loadComplete`? I have no idea who changes `contract_list`, when you do this and how you do this. Do you do this in some event handler?

Comment: I use the default editing form in jqgrid that pops up whenever someone clicks the "edit" or "add" button. The values inside of `contract_list` get populated whenever the page is loaded by retrieving values from a mysql database. Users of the website can change the values inside of the mysql database through a different part of the webpage, and if they change the values then `contract_list` gets updated with the new values, and the `select` box inside of the edit form needs to be updated with the new values. I tried updating it with `setColProp` but nothing happens whenever I call it.

Comment: Now I think I understand your problem and wrote my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your main problem will be solved if you would use [recreateForm: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) options of the form editing (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971453/how-to-add-different-texts-to-save-button-in-edit-and-add-forms-in-jqgrid/6971820#6971820) an example of the usage). I recommend you to set the setting as the default *before* you call `navGrid` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5032879/315935) the corresponding code).

Moreover from the information which you wrote in comments I think that you should better use `dataUrl` instead of `value` of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). So jqGrid can loads the list of the values directly from the server during creating of the edit form. Sometimes the usage of `buildSelect` is useful. It help you to provide the data from the server in for example JSON format and construct the `<select><option value="...">...</option>...</select>` HTML fragment based on the server data inside of `buildSelect`. Additionally it could be required to set `ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false }` jqGrid option (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422410/315935) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9615295/315935)) or to force re-validation of the previous server response on the `dataUrl` with respect of HTTP header `"Cache-Control: private, max-age=0"` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885956/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269567/315935))

Comment: Using `recreateForm: true` didn't help, however I changed my code to use `dataUrl` and now the `select` field repopulates itself through ajax every time the edit form is opened, and this shows the updated values. Thank you!