# How to prevent auto select row action when in editmode in JQGrid on click of next & prev navigation button on popup

Tags: jqgrid

when I doubleclick on the row, it will give edit popup. This edit popup has left and right error key, when I click on that Arrow key , it will select the row in background. so I want to prevent the Auto select row when click of JQGrid Editpopup's Next and previous button.[image]

so when I click on the next button it will select the row in my Grid table.How do I prevent this behavioir? in below image it mention

[image]

Please help me. I have tried "onclickPgButtons", but not able to trigger it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent selection of the new row, but you can just call `setSelection` with just selected row to *unselect* it. The code of `afterclickPgButtons` could be the following

```js
afterclickPgButtons: function (whichButton, $frmgr, justSelectedRowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid("setSelection", justSelectedRowid);
}
```

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid2.htm).

Comment: Thats what I need is.But I am not able to understand where should I put the code in my jqgrid.Following is my function of jqgrid.

 ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
     jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
                         {recreateForm:true,closeAfterEdit:true,
                          closeOnEscape:true,reloadAfterSubmit:false, title: "Edit Works"});
 }}).jqGrid("navGrid", '#workRetrievalResults_Pager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true, cloneToTop: true },

Comment: @user223614: Just open the source code of [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid2.htm). You need just open the demo, click right mouse button to open the context menu and choose the menu item "View page source" (or some other text like "View source" depend on the web browser which you use).

Comment: @Oleg, I know this is an old post but I have the same problem and your demo does not set the selection to only the selected row. I select one row and then in the edit page the "next" and "previous" buttons are still active showing more than just the selected row. Do you know if there is a way to prevent that? Thank you

Comment: @DariaM: I'm not sure that you correctly understand the problem described in the answer. I'd recommend you to open the demo in Chrome, open Developer Tools and set breakpoint on the line `$(this).jqGrid("setSelection", justSelectedRowid);` inside of `afterclickPgButtons`. You will see that **the second** row will be selected and the line unselect it. So you probably have another problem.

Comment: @Oleg. Oh Ok, I thought user223614 problem was similar to mine. I want to see only the selected records. The "view records" window has those "previous" and "next" buttons and it disconsidered my selection. Even in your demo, those buttons are not deactivated when checking only one row.  To me this is problematic, because it a user has a table on 10 rows, wants to view records of  2, 5 and 8 when he openes the view records window he expects that by pressing "next" he will see record number 5, instead jqgrid delivers the next row, which is nr 3. Is there a way to view only the selected records?

Comment: @DariaM: If you don't need "previous" and "next" buttons in add/edit/view, you can use `viewPagerButtons: false` option in the corresponding options of `navGrid` parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499309/315935 for some code example, which set the options. Alternatively, you can include `$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {viewPagerButtons: false});` or/and `$.extend($.jgrid.view, {viewPagerButtons: false});`  to change default value of `viewPagerButtons` from `true` to `false`.

Comment: @ Oleg, thank you so much for the replay. I am trying this right away.