# Canceling post of row data when inline editing finished (Per row post)

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing

Is there anyway to cancel the post of the row data to the server when editing a row inplace and accepting the edit (pressing enter)?.

I want to do this because I need to post all data at once to the server, not row by row. So, I have a button that when pressed reads the grid data and sends it to the server through an ajax call. This is why I need to cancel the per row posting.

Edit: I have noticed there's a grid option when constructing that is supposed to do what I want, but at least for me, it doesn't work, the option is cellsubmit:'clientArray'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit new here at stackoverlow. I thought voting was the way to accept it. I have accepted the correct ones. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you found the answer yourself you should write the answer on your own question and accept it. So you will help other and improve your "accepted" rate. You can also delete some your old question which you find no more interesting for you. In any way stackoverflow is community forum. The people who ask questions should make as so that **the question could help other people** and not only the person who asked the question.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. You've been really kind.

Comment: @You are welcome! The most people who not use voting or not accept the answer (like you before) not do this just because there not know the value of it. I find important two steps of reputation important 15 point (to vote) and 50 points to be able to write comment anywhere. Later reputation is not really important. To use stackoverflow more effectively I recommend you to look through the [FAQs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) if you find enough time for reading (the FAQs are not so small :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main editing modes in jqrid: cell editing, inline editing and form editing. There are additionally some hybrid solutions like `formatter: 'actions'`.

The option `cellsubmit: 'clientArray'` are used only in case of cell editing. The option `editurl: 'clientArray'` are used only for inline editing and the form editing has till not now editing of local data. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611065/adding-new-row-to-jqgrid-using-modal-form-on-client-only/5611519#5611519) I do described how one can use form editing to edit local data.

So you should probably just use `editurl: 'clientArray'` option of jqGrid.