# Treegrid with JSON and pager (add, edit, del)

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, treegrid

I'm trying to create a jQgrid with **treeGrid: true** and the options of pager (add, delete, edit, search and refresh).

I have this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Sceb/
but the options of pager not working so good.
Any ideas why this could happened?
Is a limitation of JSON data?

Thanks.

Comment: best way to get clues about your problem is to read documentation first http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid    they have clearly mentioned that paging is currently not supported in treeGrid

Comment: But in the jqGrid Demos page, there is an example of treegrid and pager with full options:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html -> Functionality -> Add tree node

Is not possible do something like that?

Comment: @FeKuLa: You use just wrong terminology in your question. I suppose that you mean [the navigator bar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator) instead of [the pager](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager). The demo from "Functionality" / "Add tree node" has **no pager**. It has only *navigator buttons*. Moreover you should describe the problem which you has more detailed as just "the options of pager not working so good". In your demo you try to use **form editing of local data** which is not currently supported in jqGrid.

Comment: @FeKuLa: If you really need local editing of the local data the corresponding code will be very long. I posted the corresponding demo in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5611519/315935).

Comment: I have a new demo using your javascript functions for local data, but I have a problem. When I add a record, the ID of TR is bad. 

Example:

<tr id="**_empty**" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">

so, I can't edit the record because the ID is empty :-(

http://jsfiddle.net/hE2GB/

Any idea about this? I'm using your code. I need any update for treegrid?