# Local form editing demo and jqGrid 4.4.1

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

This demo: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm
doesn't work properly if I update the javascript includes, to last version of jqGrid.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.formedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.inlinedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.celledit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.subgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.treegrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.grouping.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/jquery.fmatter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/jquery.searchFilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/grid.jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/jqDnR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/src/jqModal.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>-->
```

The main problem is when I add record, the ID of TR is bad.
Any update to this?

Comment: Try to add a new record: http://jsfiddle.net/8k8ct/ go to second page, and look the first column. The id of TR is "_empty"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem in the usage of [my old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm) from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611519/315935) is in the line of code

```
this.processing = true;
```

jqGrid initializes now `this` to the DOM element of the table (`$("#list")[0]`) in calls of the most callback functions. So the above line have to be fixed to

```
options.processing = true;
```

There are other small changes which should be implemented also. The most important is the calling of `$.unformat.date` to decode of all fields used by the formatter `"date"`.

The new demo used jqGrid 4.4.1 you can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing1.htm).

The full code you will find below

```
var lastSel,
    mydata = [
        {id: "1",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00"},
        {id: "2",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00"},
        {id: "3",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00"},
        {id: "4",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00"},
        {id: "5",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00"},
        {id: "6",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00"},
        {id: "7",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00"},
        {id: "8",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00"},
        {id: "9",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00"},
        {id: "10", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00"},
        {id: "11", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00"},
        {id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00"}
    ],
    grid = $("#list"),
    getColumnIndex = function (columnName) {
        var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if ((cm[i].index || cm[i].name) === columnName) {
                return i; // return the colModel index
            }
        }
        return -1;
    },
    onclickSubmitLocal = function (options, postdata) {
        var $this = $(this), grid_p = this.p,
            idname = grid_p.prmNames.id,
            grid_id = this.id,
            id_in_postdata = grid_id + "_id",
            rowid = postdata[id_in_postdata],
            addMode = rowid === "_empty",
            oldValueOfSortColumn,
            new_id,
            tr_par_id,
            colModel = grid_p.colModel,
            cmName,
            iCol,
            cm;

        // postdata has row id property with another name. we fix it:
        if (addMode) {
            // generate new id
            new_id = $.jgrid.randId();
            while ($("#" + new_id).length !== 0) {
                new_id = $.jgrid.randId();
            }
            postdata[idname] = String(new_id);
        } else if (typeof postdata[idname] === "undefined") {
            // set id property only if the property not exist
            postdata[idname] = rowid;
        }
        delete postdata[id_in_postdata];

        // prepare postdata for tree grid
        if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
            if (addMode) {
                tr_par_id = grid_p.treeGridModel === 'adjacency' ? grid_p.treeReader.parent_id_field : 'parent_id';
                postdata[tr_par_id] = grid_p.selrow;
            }

            $.each(grid_p.treeReader, function (i) {
                if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(this)) {
                    delete postdata[this];
                }
            });
        }

        // decode data if there encoded with autoencode
        if (grid_p.autoencode) {
            $.each(postdata, function (n, v) {
                postdata[n] = $.jgrid.htmlDecode(v); // TODO: some columns could be skipped
            });
        }

        // save old value from the sorted column
        oldValueOfSortColumn = grid_p.sortname === "" ? undefined : grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, grid_p.sortname);

        // save the data in the grid
        if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
            if (addMode) {
                $this.jqGrid("addChildNode", new_id, grid_p.selrow, postdata);
            } else {
                $this.jqGrid("setTreeRow", rowid, postdata);
            }
        } else {
            if (addMode) {
                // we need unformat all date fields before calling of addRowData
                for (cmName in postdata) {
                    if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(cmName)) {
                        iCol = getColumnIndex.call(this, cmName);
                        if (iCol >= 0) {
                            cm = colModel[iCol];
                            if (cm && cm.formatter === "date") {
                                postdata[cmName] = $.unformat.date.call(this, postdata[cmName], cm);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $this.jqGrid("addRowData", new_id, postdata, options.addedrow);
            } else {
                $this.jqGrid("setRowData", rowid, postdata);
            }
        }

        if ((addMode && options.closeAfterAdd) || (!addMode && options.closeAfterEdit)) {
            // close the edit/add dialog
            $.jgrid.hideModal("#editmod" + grid_id, {
                gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id,
                jqm: options.jqModal,
                onClose: options.onClose
            });
        }

        if (postdata[grid_p.sortname] !== oldValueOfSortColumn) {
            // if the data are changed in the column by which are currently sorted
            // we need resort the grid
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
            }, 100);
        }

        // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
        options.processing = true;
        return {};
    },
    editSettings = {
        //recreateForm: true,
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
    },
    addSettings = {
        //recreateForm: true,
        jqModal: false,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        savekey: [true, 13],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
    },
    delSettings = {
        // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes to the server
        // so I use "processing:true" setting and delete the row manually in onclickSubmit
        onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
            var $this = $(this), grid_id = $.jgrid.jqID(this.id), grid_p = this.p,
                newPage = grid_p.page;

            // reset the value of processing option to true to
            // skip the ajax request to 'clientArray'.
            options.processing = true;

            // delete the row
            if (grid_p.treeGrid) {
                $this.jqGrid("delTreeNode", rowid);
            } else {
                $this.jqGrid("delRowData", rowid);
            }
            $.jgrid.hideModal("#delmod" + grid_id, {
                gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id,
                jqm: options.jqModal,
                onClose: options.onClose
            });

            if (grid_p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
                if (grid_p.reccount === 0 && newPage === grid_p.lastpage) {
                    // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
                    // which is the last page of the grid
                    newPage--; // go to the previous page
                }
                // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: newPage}]);
            }

            return true;
        },
        processing: true
    },
    initDateEdit = function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                //autoSize: true,
                showOn: 'button',
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
        }, 100);
    },
    initDateSearch = function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                //autoSize: true,
                //showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
        }, 100);
    };

grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: mydata,
    colNames: [/*'Inv No', */'Client', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Closed', 'Shipped via', 'Notes'],
    colModel: [
        //{name: 'id', width: 70, align: 'center', sorttype: 'int', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq', 'ne']}},
        {name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: true, width: 60, editrules: {required: true}},
        {name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date',
            formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'd-M-Y'}, editable: true, datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
            editoptions: {dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14},
            searchoptions: {dataInit: initDateSearch}},
        {name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 70, formatter: 'number', editable: true, align: 'right'},
        {name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 50, formatter: 'number', editable: true, align: 'right'},
        {name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 60, formatter: 'number', editable: true, align: 'right'},
        {name: 'closed', index: 'closed', width: 70, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox',
            edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: {value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes'},
            stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':All;true:Yes;false:No'}},
        {name: 'ship_via', index: 'ship_via', width: 100, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim', defaultValue: 'Intime'},
            stype: 'select', searchoptions: {value: ':All;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim'}},
        {name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea'}
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: '#pager',
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    autoencode: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    sortname: 'invdate',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    caption: 'How to implement local form editing',
    height: '100%',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, ri, ci) {
        var $this = $(this), p = this.p;
        if (p.selrow !== rowid) {
            // prevent the row from be unselected on double-click
            // the implementation is for "multiselect:false" which we use,
            // but one can easy modify the code for "multiselect:true"
            $this.jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
        }
        $this.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, editSettings);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSel) {
            // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
            // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
            // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
            // if jqGrid not in editing state
            if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
            }
            lastSel = id;
        }
    }
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {}, editSettings, addSettings, delSettings,
    {multipleSearch: true, overlay: false,
        onClose: function (form) {
            // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
            // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
            // the div used by datepicker
            $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
        }});
```

P.S. I don't tested the code with TreeGrid, but I hope it should work too. Probably one will need to make the same call of `$.unformat.date` on the columns with "date" formatter too.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a lot.
A little modification for delete:
if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
$this.jqGrid("delTreeNode", rowid);
}else{
$this.jqGrid("delRowData", rowid);
}