# Issue with sending all data to the server after local adding rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hi I am a newbie to jqGrid. I am using jqGrid 4.4. I have successfully used the approach by Oleg in

[Adding new row to jqGrid using modal form on client only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611065/adding-new-row-to-jqgrid-using-modal-form-on-client-only/5611519#5611519)

to add rows locally. There are 2 issues I am facing

1. The row that is not added to the end , how can I achieve this?
2. I send all the rows on click of a button as below:

I always get the alert in the error block?

```
    $("#sendButton").click(function(){
    var gridData = jQuery("#list").getRowData();
    var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(gridData);             
    var postData = myJSONString.replace(/[\"]/g, '\"');     
    alert("JSON serialized jqGrid data:\n" + postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: CONTEXT_ROOT+"/json",
        data : postData,
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error:"+errorThrown+" textStatus : "+textStatus);
        }           
    });
});
```

Not sure what I need to return once I save in the java controller. Here is the code in the controller. I also tried with the return as void but same result. Also is there a better approach to bind the list of json objects coming from the jsp to a list of domain objects. I have tried Binding when there is only a single object like from the form using @RequestBody as explained in

http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveNewCasePackOptions(@RequestBody List<Map> json) {

    for(Map mJson : json){  
        String idCasePkOptions = (String)mJson.get("idCasePackOptions");            
        Long idCasePackOptions = (idCasePkOptions.isEmpty())?null:new Long(idCasePkOptions);
        Short cypharecommended =  new Short((String)mJson.get("cypharecommended"));
        Short distributorapproved = new Short((String)mJson.get("distributorapproved"));
        String heightStr = (String)mJson.get("height");
        Double height = (heightStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(heightStr);

        String lengthStr = (String)mJson.get("length");
        Double length = (lengthStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(lengthStr);

        String weightStr = (String)mJson.get("height");
        Double weight = (weightStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(weightStr);

        String widthStr = (String)mJson.get("width");
        Double width = (widthStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(widthStr);      

        String stateString = (String)mJson.get("statuscode");
        stateString = (stateString.contains("Green"))?"1":"0";          
        Short statuscode = new Short(stateString);

        CasePackOptions casePkOpt = new CasePackOptions(idCasePackOptions, cypharecommended, distributorapproved, height, length, statuscode, weight, width);  

        System.out.println(casePkOpt);

        casePackOptionsService.save(casePkOpt);
    }
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();      
    mav.setViewName("casepackoptions/listPage1.jsp");
    return mav;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the answer on the first part of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296186/315935).

The answer on the second part of your question you could receive from the people who used Spring. The part `myJSONString.replace(/[\"]/g, '\"')` seems very suspect for me. Probably you will need to use `data : {json: postData}` instead of `data : postData`. Probably you will need to change `@RequestBody` to `@RequestParam` or `@RequestParam("json")`. I don't use Spring myself.

Additionally you can use `$("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` instead of `jQuery("#list").getRowData()`. It will be especially helpful if you uses local paging of the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Oleg, the first part of the problem is resolved. And I have followed your advice to use $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") however I am getting a value of _id_":"1" in my json string not sure where it is coming from  [{"idCasePackOptions":3,"cypharecommended":2,"distributorapproved":1,"height":11,"length":11,"statuscode":1,"weight":11,"width":11,"_id_":"1"}]  Is there any disadvantages of using jQuery("#list").getRowData() ? I have also added loadonce: true so that once I get the data in the grid it will be local paging.

Comment: @rsingh: You are welcome! You don't posted the grid definition which you use. So it's difficult to give you recommendations. If you use `datatype: 'local'` or any other with exception `datatype: 'json'` (or 'xml') and not use `loadonce: true` the way with `.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` is better because it get the data from *all pages*. Only in case of pure remote data you have to use `getRowData`. If you get wrong `id` values then the typical reason is **wrong filling** of the grid. If you has correct `id` in some column you can add `key: true` property to the column to fix the problem.

Comment: This is now working now I have added subgrids successfully is it possible to post all the data of the main and subgrid. Have you got any examples for this? How to post this onetomany data? My question with code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469690/jqgrid-subgrid-post-all-data-to-server. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks oleg

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working but not really sure if this is the recommended way.

java script function is

```
$("#sendButton").click(function(){
    var gridData = jQuery("#list").getRowData();
    gridData = JSON.stringify(gridData);    
    alert("postData stringify data :\n" + postData);
    postData = postData.replace();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: CONTEXT_ROOT+"/json",
        data : gridData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {             
            alert("error:"+errorThrown+" textStatus : "+textStatus);
        }           
    });
});
```

Server code is now

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveNewCasePackOptions(@RequestBody List<Map> json) {
    for(Map mJson : json){  
        String idCasePkOptions = (String)mJson.get("idCasePackOptions");            
        Long idCasePackOptions = (idCasePkOptions.isEmpty())?null:new Long(idCasePkOptions);
        Short cypharecommended =  new Short((String)mJson.get("cypharecommended"));
        Short distributorapproved = new Short((String)mJson.get("distributorapproved"));
        String heightStr = (String)mJson.get("height");
        Double height = (heightStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(heightStr);

        String lengthStr = (String)mJson.get("length");
        Double length = (lengthStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(lengthStr);

        String weightStr = (String)mJson.get("height");
        Double weight = (weightStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(weightStr);

        String widthStr = (String)mJson.get("width");
        Double width = (widthStr.isEmpty())?null:new Double(widthStr);      

        String stateString = (String)mJson.get("statuscode");           
        Short statuscode = new Short(stateString);

        CasePackOptions casePkOpt = new CasePackOptions(idCasePackOptions, cypharecommended, distributorapproved, height, length, statuscode, weight, width);  

        System.out.println(casePkOpt);

        casePackOptionsService.save(casePkOpt);
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

Things that feel like they need to be done differently

1. When I try to use  $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"); instead of jQuery("#list").getRowData(); I was getting id:"1" as part of my Json string
2. When trying to use data : {json: postData} instead of data : postData the json object in firebug was encoded like this

json=%5B%7B%22idCasePackOptions%22%3A%221%22%2C%22cypharecommended%22%3A%221%22%2C%22distributorapproved%22%3A%222%22%2C%22height%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22length%22%3A%2255%22%2C%22statuscode%22%3A%221%22%2C%22weight%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22width%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks