# BeforeSubmit & ClearAfterAdd Events not firing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I adapted this link [Local form editing demo and jqGrid 4.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281463/local-form-editing-demo-and-jqgrid-4-4-1/12296186#12296186) to fit my solution, however I have changed the `CloseAfterAdd:false` and added `ClearAfterAdd:true` and `beforeSubmit: CheckValid`. However both events are not firing to accomplish my goal. My goals are to keep the dialog form open while adding records using the enter key as the savekey and clear the form after that save. Secondly validate a set of related fields in the CheckValid function. Please can someone point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks

```
function checkvalue(value, colname) { alert(value || colname); return [true, ""]; }
        var vlcontractor, field2, field3, field4, vlBuckid, vlHospid, myCustomCheck, myCustomCheck2;
        myCustomCheck = function (value, colname) {
            switch (colname) {
                case 'Contractor':
                    vlcontractor = value;
                    break;
                case 'Company Name':
                    field2 = value;
                    break;
                case 'Project End Date':
                    field3 = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (vlcontractor == "Yes" && (field2 == undefined || field3 == undefined))
            { return [false, "Company/State ID/End Date is needed for a Contractor"]; }

            if (vlcontractor != undefined  && field2 != undefined) {
                // validate the fields here
                return [false, "some error text"];
            } else {
                //alert('we are good');
                return [true];
            }
        };
        myCustomCheck2 = function (value, colname) {
            switch (colname) {
                case 'BUCK ID':
                    vlBuckid = value;
                    break;
                case 'Hospital ID':
                    vlHospid = value;
                    break;
            }
            if ((vlBuckid == undefined && vlHospid == undefined) || (vlBuckid == '' && vlHospid == ''))
            { return [false, "A BuckID or Hospital ID is required."]; }
            else { return [true]; }
        }

        $(function () {
            var lastSel,
            mydata = '',
                grid = $("#list"),
                getColumnIndex = function (columnName) {
                    var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        if ((cm[i].index || cm[i].name) === columnName) {
                            return i; // return the colModel index
                        }
                    }
                    return -1;
                },
                CheckValid = function (postdata, formid) {
                    alert(postdata);
                    return false;
                },
                onclickSubmitLocal = function (options, postdata) {
                    var $this = $(this), grid_p = this.p,
                        idname = grid_p.prmNames.id,
                        grid_id = this.id,
                        id_in_postdata = grid_id + "_id",
                        rowid = postdata[id_in_postdata],
                        addMode = rowid === "_empty",
                        oldValueOfSortColumn,
                        new_id,
                        tr_par_id,
                        colModel = grid_p.colModel,
                        cmName,
                        iCol,
                        cm;

                    // postdata has row id property with another name. we fix it:
                    if (addMode) {
                        // generate new id
                        new_id = $.jgrid.randId();
                        while ($("#" + new_id).length !== 0) {
                            new_id = $.jgrid.randId();
                        }
                        postdata[idname] = String(new_id);
                    } else if (typeof postdata[idname] === "undefined") {
                        // set id property only if the property not exist
                        postdata[idname] = rowid;
                    }
                    delete postdata[id_in_postdata];

                    // prepare postdata for tree grid
                    if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
                        if (addMode) {
                            tr_par_id = grid_p.treeGridModel === 'adjacency' ? grid_p.treeReader.parent_id_field : 'parent_id';
                            postdata[tr_par_id] = grid_p.selrow;
                        }

                        $.each(grid_p.treeReader, function (i) {
                            if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(this)) {
                                delete postdata[this];
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    // decode data if there encoded with autoencode
                    if (grid_p.autoencode) {
                        $.each(postdata, function (n, v) {
                            postdata[n] = $.jgrid.htmlDecode(v); // TODO: some columns could be skipped
                        });
                    }

                    // save old value from the sorted column
                    oldValueOfSortColumn = grid_p.sortname === "" ? undefined : grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, grid_p.sortname);

                    // save the data in the grid
                    if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
                        if (addMode) {
                            $this.jqGrid("addChildNode", new_id, grid_p.selrow, postdata);
                        } else {
                            $this.jqGrid("setTreeRow", rowid, postdata);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (addMode) {
                            // we need unformat all date fields before calling of addRowData
                            for (cmName in postdata) {
                                if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(cmName)) {
                                    iCol = getColumnIndex.call(this, cmName);
                                    if (iCol >= 0) {
                                        cm = colModel[iCol];
                                        if (cm && cm.formatter === "date") {
                                            postdata[cmName] = $.unformat.date.call(this, postdata[cmName], cm);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            $this.jqGrid("addRowData", new_id, postdata, options.addedrow);
                        } else {
                            $this.jqGrid("setRowData", rowid, postdata);
                        }
                    }

                    if ((addMode && options.closeAfterAdd) || (!addMode && options.closeAfterEdit)) {
                        // close the edit/add dialog
                        $.jgrid.hideModal("#editmod" + grid_id, {
                            gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id,
                            jqm: options.jqModal,
                            onClose: options.onClose
                        });
                    }

                    if (postdata[grid_p.sortname] !== oldValueOfSortColumn) {
                        // if the data are changed in the column by which are currently sorted
                        // we need resort the grid
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
                        }, 100);
                    }

                    // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
                    options.processing = true;
                    $('#gridData').val(JSON.stringify(grid_p.data));
                    return {};
                },
                editSettings = {
                    //recreateForm: true,
                    jqModal: false,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    savekey: [true, 13],
                    closeAfterEdit: true,
                    beforeSubmit: CheckValid,
                    onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
                },
                addSettings = {
                    //recreateForm: true,
                    jqModal: false,
                    beforeSubmit: CheckValid,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                    savekey: [true, 13],
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    closeAfterAdd: true,
                    clearAfterAdd: true,
                    onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
                },
                delSettings = {
                    // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes to the server
                    // so I use "processing:true" setting and delete the row manually in onclickSubmit
                    onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
                        var $this = $(this), grid_id = $.jgrid.jqID(this.id), grid_p = this.p,
                            newPage = grid_p.page;

                        // reset the value of processing option to true to
                        // skip the ajax request to 'clientArray'.
                        options.processing = true;

                        // delete the row
                        $this.jqGrid("delRowData", rowid);
                        if (grid_p.treeGrid) {
                            $this.jqGrid("delTreeNode", rowid);
                        } else {
                            $this.jqGrid("delRowData", rowid);
                        }
                        $.jgrid.hideModal("#delmod" + grid_id, {
                            gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id,
                            jqm: options.jqModal,
                            onClose: options.onClose
                        });

                        if (grid_p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
                            if (grid_p.reccount === 0 && newPage === grid_p.lastpage) {
                                // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
                                // which is the last page of the grid
                                newPage--; // go to the previous page
                            }
                            // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                            $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: newPage}]);
                        }

                        return true;
                    },
                    processing: true
                },
                initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                            //autoSize: true,
                            showOn: 'button',
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            showWeek: true
                        });
                    }, 100);
                },
                initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                            //autoSize: true,
                            //showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            showWeek: true
                        });
                    }, 100);
                };
            grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local',
                data: mydata,
                //colNames: [/*'Inv No', */'Client', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Closed', 'Shipped via', 'Notes'],
                colNames: ['Emp/Stu ID', 'Last Name, First Name', 'BUCK ID', 'Hospital ID', 'Contractor', 'Company-Name', 'State ID', 'Project End Date'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'empstuid', index: 'empstuid', editable: true, width: 80, editrules: { required: false }, editoptions: { maxlength: 10 } },
                        { name: 'lastFirst', index: 'lastFirst', editable: true, width: 180, editrules: { required: true} },
                        { name: 'buckid', index: 'buckid', editable: true, width: 120, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: myCustomCheck2 } },
                        { name: 'hospid', index: 'hospid', editable: true, width: 120, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: myCustomCheck2 } },
                        {
                            name: 'contractor', index: 'contractor', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox',
                            editoptions: { value: "Yes:No" }, width: 70, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func:myCustomCheck }
                        },
                        { name: 'compname', index: 'compname', editable: true, width: 110, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func:myCustomCheck } },
                        { name: 'stateid', index: 'stateid', editable: true, width: 80, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: myCustomCheck } },
                        { name: 'enddate', index: 'enddate', editable: true, width: 110, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: myCustomCheck } }
                ],
                altRows: true,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20],
                pager: '#pager',
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                sortname: 'invdate',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                footerrow: true,
                emptyrecords:"There are **no records added",
                caption: '',
                height: '100%',
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                ondblClickRow: function (rowid, ri, ci) {
                    var $this = $(this), p = this.p;
                    if (p.selrow !== rowid) {
                        // prevent the row from be unselected on double-click
                        // the implementation is for "multiselect:false" which we use,
                        // but one can easy modify the code for "multiselect:true"
                        $this.jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
                    }
                    $this.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, editSettings);
                },
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                        // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
                        // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
                        // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
                        // if jqGrid not in editing state
                        if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                            $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                        }
                        lastSel = id;
                    }
                }
            }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit:false,add:true, del:true, search:false, refresh:false}, editSettings, addSettings, delSettings,
                { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false,
                    onClose: function (form) {
                        // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
                        // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
                        // the div used by datepicker
                        $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback `beforeSubmit` do fired, but only in case of successful validation.

The way how you use custom validation is wrong. For example if you check `contractor` value you will get `"Company/State ID/End Date is needed for a Contractor"` error message event if the company is filled. The problem is that the variable `field2` which you set inside of `myCustomCheck` during validation of `'compname'` column will be set *after* the validation of `'contractor'` where `field2` will be used.

If you need implement of custom validation of **multiple fields** you should better use `beforeCheckValues` callback. The callback will be called *before* all other validations. It get `postdata` with **all fields** as input. So you can easy validate the data. The callback can don't have any `return` (or use `return;` without any value). You can add validation rule having `custom: true, custom_func` *only for one column*. Inside of the validation function you can return `[false, errorMessage]` if validation error was found in `beforeCheckValues` callback.

Moreover I don'r recommend you to declare any functions or variables *outside* of `$(function () {...});`. You should place all code inside of it. In the way you will reduce the number of global variables.