# clearAfterAdd Event not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Currently I have my formedit working using the [Enter key] to save records to the grid while keeping the form open. My understanding from the jqgrid wikiDoc was the clearAfterAdd will clear the fields on the modal form for the entry of the next record, however this event is not working. Can anyone shed some insight. Here is my code below.

```
        var lastSel,
            mydata = [
                { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" }
            ],
            grid = $("#list"),
            getColumnIndex = function (columnName) {
                var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    if ((cm[i].index || cm[i].name) === columnName) {
                        return i; // return the colModel index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            },
            onclickSubmitLocal = function (options, postdata) {
                var $this = $(this), grid_p = this.p,
                    idname = grid_p.prmNames.id,
                    grid_id = this.id,
                    id_in_postdata = grid_id + "_id",
                    rowid = postdata[id_in_postdata],
                    addMode = rowid === "_empty",
                    oldValueOfSortColumn,
                    new_id,
                    tr_par_id,
                    colModel = grid_p.colModel,
                    cmName,
                    iCol,
                    cm;

                // postdata has row id property with another name. we fix it:
                if (addMode) {
                    // generate new id
                    new_id = $.jgrid.randId();
                    while ($("#" + new_id).length !== 0) {
                        new_id = $.jgrid.randId();
                    }
                    postdata[idname] = String(new_id);
                } else if (typeof postdata[idname] === "undefined") {
                    // set id property only if the property not exist
                    postdata[idname] = rowid;
                }
                delete postdata[id_in_postdata];

                // prepare postdata for tree grid
                if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
                    if (addMode) {
                        tr_par_id = grid_p.treeGridModel === 'adjacency' ? grid_p.treeReader.parent_id_field : 'parent_id';
                        postdata[tr_par_id] = grid_p.selrow;
                    }

                    $.each(grid_p.treeReader, function (i) {
                        if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(this)) {
                            delete postdata[this];
                        }
                    });
                }

                // decode data if there encoded with autoencode
                if (grid_p.autoencode) {
                    $.each(postdata, function (n, v) {
                        postdata[n] = $.jgrid.htmlDecode(v); // TODO: some columns could be skipped
                    });
                }

                // save old value from the sorted column
                oldValueOfSortColumn = grid_p.sortname === "" ? undefined : grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, grid_p.sortname);

                // save the data in the grid
                if (grid_p.treeGrid === true) {
                    if (addMode) {
                        $this.jqGrid("addChildNode", new_id, grid_p.selrow, postdata);
                    } else {
                        $this.jqGrid("setTreeRow", rowid, postdata);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (addMode) {
                        // we need unformat all date fields before calling of addRowData
                        for (cmName in postdata) {
                            if (postdata.hasOwnProperty(cmName)) {
                                iCol = getColumnIndex.call(this, cmName);
                                if (iCol >= 0) {
                                    cm = colModel[iCol];
                                    if (cm && cm.formatter === "date") {
                                        postdata[cmName] = $.unformat.date.call(this, postdata[cmName], cm);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $this.jqGrid("addRowData", new_id, postdata, options.addedrow);
                    } else {
                        $this.jqGrid("setRowData", rowid, postdata);
                    }
                }

                if ((addMode && options.closeAfterAdd) || (!addMode && options.closeAfterEdit)) {
                    // close the edit/add dialog
                    $.jgrid.hideModal("#editmod" + grid_id, {
                        gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id,
                        jqm: options.jqModal,
                        onClose: options.onClose
                    });
                }

                if (postdata[grid_p.sortname] !== oldValueOfSortColumn) {
                    // if the data are changed in the column by which are currently sorted
                    // we need resort the grid
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
                    }, 100);
                }

                // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
                options.processing = true;
                return {};
            },
            editSettings = {
                //recreateForm: true,
                jqModal: false,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                savekey: [true, 13],
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
            },
            addSettings = {
                recreateForm: true,
                jqModal: false,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                savekey: [true, 13],
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: false,
                clearAfterAdd: true,
                onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
            }
                processing: true
            }
            };

        grid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: mydata,
            colNames: [/*'Inv No', */'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total'],
            colModel: [
                //{name: 'id', width: 70, align: 'center', sorttype: 'int', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq', 'ne']}},
                {name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: true, width: 60, editrules: {required: true}},
                {name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 70, formatter: 'number', editable: true, align: 'right'},
                {name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 50, formatter: 'number', editable: true, align: 'right'},
                {name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 60, formatter: 'number', editable: true, align: 'right'}
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            pager: '#pager',
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            autoencode: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            sortname: 'invdate',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            caption: 'How to implement local form editing',
            height: '100%',
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid, ri, ci) {
                var $this = $(this), p = this.p;
                if (p.selrow !== rowid) {
                    // prevent the row from be unselected on double-click
                    // the implementation is for "multiselect:false" which we use,
                    // but one can easy modify the code for "multiselect:true"
                    $this.jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
                }
                $this.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, editSettings);
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                    // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
                    // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
                    // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
                    // if jqGrid not in editing state
                    if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                        $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                    }
                    lastSel = id;
                }
            }
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {}, editSettings, addSettings, delSettings,
            {multipleSearch: true, overlay: false,
                onClose: function (form) {
                    // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
                    // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
                    // the div used by datepicker
                    $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
                }});
```

Comment: You would not expect people to dig into so much code, do you? Post a jsFiddle sample, or shorten your code.

Answer (score 0):

You use the code which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296186/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611519/315935). I wrote you in my answer on your previous question that jqGrid don't support editing of local data if you use form editing mode. The code which I posted was the attempt to implement a workaround which could do use the most features of form editing with local data. The code of `onclickSubmitLocal` was written based on the code of `complete` event handler of `editGridRow` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L711-L816)). If you examine [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L749-L779) of the code you will see that in combination of options `closeAfterAdd: false, clearAfterAdd: true` the **internal** function `fillData` (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L769)) will be called

```js
fillData("_empty",$t,frmgr);
```

As I wrote the code I would have to remove the part, because `fillData` was not accessible from outside.

What you can do is to use `afterComplete` callback to reset all fields on the input form to the default values. The common code which should be done you find [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L518-L551), but in every specific case the filling if input filed will be much easier.