# jqGrid: Custom handling of submit button in edit form?

Tags: jqgrid, form-editing

I am working on form editing in jqGrid. I am using completely local data (array) for populating the grid; no talking to the server for any reason. I have the edit button in the pager, and clicking it brings up the edit form.

1. Now I need the submit button in the edit form to work in the default way (all validations, showing error messages etc) except *it should not try to submit to the server* (and end up saying *no url is set*).
2. Instead i need to *save the edited values* (after validation) *back to the row and grid*. Is that possible?
3. If not, I suppose I have to add a custom button in the edit form. I tried. But how do I invoke all the custom validation handlers tied with the fields and show the error messages like the default way?

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid don't supports local editing in case of usage *form editing*. Only inline editing and cell editing support local editing. One should just set `editurl: "clientArray"`. So the easiest way to solve all your problems is the usage of inline editing instead of form editing.

Nevertheless local editing can do be implemented in case of usage *form editing*. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847745/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing2.htm) is modification of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296186/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611519/315935). I posted my original answer almost 3 years ago. Because of some modifications in jqGrid the code need be modified a little. The last demo uses the current 4.5.4 version and it works. So you can uses the code to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a ton #Oleg! It took some time for me to get it working. The options.processing = true was subtle to note and did the trick. We owe you.

Comment: I am facing a follow-on problem. I have posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194964/jqgrid-form-edits-saved-to-row-but-all-changes-lost-when-paging-back-or-forth. SOS!

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: The code from your question don't use the code which I referenced here. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing2.htm) don't have the problem which you described.

Comment: I am replying in the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194964/jqgrid-form-edits-saved-to-row-but-all-changes-lost-when-paging-back-or-forth. Let us continue the discussion there.

Comment: Updated the unsuccessful results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194964/jqgrid-form-edits-saved-to-row-but-all-changes-lost-when-paging-back-or-forth