# jqGrid: Form edits saved to row but all changes lost when paging back or forth

Tags: jqgrid, form-editing

I am using form editing for local data. I am able to edit the values in the form and set the values back to the row (using setRowData). **But when I page back or forth, the changes are lost.**

*How do I save the changes to the row and the underlying source in the grid?* Later I have to iterate the rows, validate all the errors are corrected (using the edit form), and post it to server.

Code:

```
var gridId = 'mygrid';
var pagerId = 'mygridpager';

var grid = $('#mygrid');
var pager = $('#mygridpager');

grid.jqGrid({
    caption: caption,
    colModel: getColModel(),
    recreateForm: true,

    hidegrid: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    multiselect: true,
    rownumbers: true,

    autowidth: true,
    height: '100%',
    scrollOffset: 0,

    datatype: 'local',
    data: dataAsArray,
    localReader: {
        repeatitems: true,
        cell: '',
        id: 2
    },

    pager: '#' + pagerId,
    pgbuttons: true,
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [2, 5, 7, 10, 250, 500]
});

grid.jqGrid('navGrid',
    '#' + pagerId,
    {
        add: false,
        del: false,
        search: false,

        edit: true,
        edittext: 'Fix Error',
        editicon: 'ui-icon-tag',
        editurl: 'clientArray',

        refreshtext: 'Refresh',
        recreateForm: true
    },
    {
        // edit options
        editCaption: 'Fix Error',
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        recreateForm: true,
        beforeShowForm: function(form) {
            /* Custom style for elements. make it disabled etc */
        },
        onclickSubmit: function(options, postdata) {
                    var idName= $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam').prmNames.id;

                    // [UPDATED]
                    if (postdata[idName] === undefined) {
                        var idInPostdata = this.id + "_id";
                        postdata[idName] = postdata[idInPostdata];
                        postdata['row'] = postdata[idInPostdata];
                    }

            $('#mygrid').jqGrid('setRowData', postdata.row, postdata);

            if (options.closeAfterEdit) {
                $.jgrid.hideModal('#editmod' + gridId, {
                    gb: '#gbox_' + gridId,
                    jqm: options.jqModal,
                    onClose: options.onClose
                });
            }

            options.processing = true;

            return {};
        }
    },
    {}, // add options
    {}, // del options
    {} //search options
).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Oleg said, "The code from your question don't use the code which I referenced here. The demo don't have the problem which you described."

Comment: @Oleg Yeah I referenced the code from your demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing2.htm but actually borrowed parts of it, not the entire onclickSubmitLocal function. I am not sure what I am missing!

Comment: @Oleg, I have compared the demo with my code (updated above), and could not get it working. Something is missing, not sure what!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the reason of your problem is usage of array format (`repeatitems: true` in `localReader`) of input data. I suppose that you need build array from `postdata` and use it as the  parameter of `setRowData` instead of `postdata`.

If the advice will don't help you that you should post more full code of the grid with the test data. The code like `colModel: getColModel(),` don't really help. In other words you should post enough information to *reproduce* the problem. The best would be a working demo in http://jsfiddle.net/. If you prepare such demo please use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

**UPDATED**: The problem in your code is the usage arrays is items if input `data` (you use `repeatitems: true` in `localReader`). The current implementation of `setRowData` don't support (works incorrect) in the case. For example if you have such data initially

[image]

and start editing of the third row you will have something like the following

[image]

after usage the like `$('#mygrid').jqGrid('setRowData', postdata.row, postdata);` inside of `onclickSubmit`. So the internal data will be incorrectly modified.

To fix the problem I suggest overwrite the current implementation of `setRowData` by including the following code

```js
$.jgrid.extend({
    setRowData : function(rowid, data, cssp) {
        var nm, success=true, title;
        this.each(function(){
            if(!this.grid) {return false;}
            var t = this, vl, ind, cp = typeof cssp, lcdata=t.p.datatype === "local" && t.p.localReader.repeatitems === true? [] : {}, iLocal=0;
            ind = $(this).jqGrid('getGridRowById', rowid);
            if(!ind) { return false; }
            if( data ) {
                try {
                    $(this.p.colModel).each(function(i){
                        nm = this.name;
                        var dval =$.jgrid.getAccessor(data,nm);
                        if( dval !== undefined) {
                            vl = this.formatter && typeof this.formatter === 'string' && this.formatter === 'date' ? $.unformat.date.call(t,dval,this) : dval;
                            if (t.p.datatype === "local" && t.p.localReader.repeatitems === true) {
                                lcdata[iLocal] = vl;
                            } else {
                                lcdata[nm] = vl;
                            }
                            vl = t.formatter( rowid, dval, i, data, 'edit');
                            title = this.title ? {"title":$.jgrid.stripHtml(vl)} : {};
                            if(t.p.treeGrid===true && nm === t.p.ExpandColumn) {
                                $("td[role='gridcell']:eq("+i+") > span:first",ind).html(vl).attr(title);
                            } else {
                                $("td[role='gridcell']:eq("+i+")",ind).html(vl).attr(title);
                            }
                        }
                        if (nm !== "cb" && nm !== "subgrid" && nm !== "rn") {
                            iLocal++;
                        }
                    });
                    if(t.p.datatype === 'local') {
                        var id = $.jgrid.stripPref(t.p.idPrefix, rowid),
                        pos = t.p._index[id], key;
                        if(t.p.treeGrid) {
                            for(key in t.p.treeReader){
                                if(t.p.treeReader.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                    delete lcdata[t.p.treeReader[key]];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(pos !== undefined) {
                            t.p.data[pos] = $.extend(true, t.p.data[pos], lcdata);
                        }
                        lcdata = null;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    success = false;
                }
            }
            if(success) {
                if(cp === 'string') {$(ind).addClass(cssp);} else if(cssp !== null && cp === 'object') {$(ind).css(cssp);}
                $(t).triggerHandler("jqGridAfterGridComplete");
            }
        });
        return success;
    }
});
```

I will post my suggestion later to trirand. So one can hopes that the problem will be fixed in the next version of jqGrid.

Comment: If I set repeatitems to false, grid rows are empty. Tried cloning the object passed to setRowData but did not work; changes are lost. Have created a sample (almost close to my real code): https://sites.google.com/site/kenbase/misc/formedit.html. You should be able to run it locally on the machine.

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: I updated my answer. New (fixed) implementation of `setRowData` method should fix your problem.

Comment: From the look of it, it appears to be safer to make the input data JSON instead of array. But I am not going to do that. Because the input data for my grid is from a CSV file, and having the input as JSON makes the data bulky (column names in every row/object is redundant), and i will have to validate the data for the presence of these column/attribute names. So thanks a million @Oleg for this. You are awesome, man! I am going ahead with the fix you have provided. Hopefully the jqGrid team fixes the issue soon.

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: I tried the fix on the sample (formedit.html) and it worked. But it does not work in my real code. I think I found the issue. Let me confirm with you. Is it correct to assume that the core of your fix is "t.p.data[pos] = $.extend(true, t.p.data[pos], lcdata);"? The above code replaces the old data in the internal rows with the new data (lcdata - new array constructed) at the index 'pos', which means it replaces the data in the array referred by index, assuming the rowid parameter passed to the setRowData is the index. Continued...

Comment: But I think that the rowid parameter in the setRowData is not the index of the row, it is the something that the row is identified by; an id, in my case it is the row number in the csv file. Continued...

Comment: So pos and rowid in my case are not the same, therefore the update is not applied at the right place internally and hence are lost. Is my understanding correct? So, for now, I have iterated and this.p.data in oclickSubmit and updated the relevant record. The above patch works but unfortunately it will not work for me in the real code since I have to construct an array (like lcdata) from postdata with the values at the proper indices; else the values may be out of order. I will not know the indices since the actual rows come from the CSV file. Makes sense? Let me know what you think @Oleg.

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: The main changes which I suggested is changing the way how `lcdata` will be filled in case of `repeatitems: true`. The problem which you could have now could be id duplicates for example. By the way if you use more as one grid on the page I recommend you use `idPrefix` option. The code `t.p.data[pos] = $.extend(true, t.p.data[pos], lcdata);` uses `pos` which will get from `_ibdex`: `pos = t.p._index[id]`. Map `_index` helps to find position in `t.p.data` array by rowid.

Comment: I verified and there are no id duplicates. For now, I am manually copying the values to the respective indices in this.p.data. It is working but I doubt if that is cleaner or the right way. Thanks.