# local form editing /adding using jqgrid 4.6.0 plugin

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid table in which I display my data,locally.
I need to add record,edit record and delete.I referred to [Multiple jqGrid on one page, how to identify which grid on when click on "add" button on navigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836676/multiple-jqgrid-on-one-page-how-to-identify-which-grid-on-when-click-on-add-b/19847745#19847745) for jqgrid 4.5.4 version.

The add record doesn't work for me on jqgrid 4.6.0 version.It adds record succesfully only the first time.On subsequent attempts,The issue I am facing is,
onClickSubmit has postdata row values empty.So as result,it adds blank rows.

The code I use is exactly same as mentioned in the link above.The only change is my JSON data is :

```
data = [{'fname':'abc','lname':'def'},
        {'fname':'efg','lname':'xyz'}]
```

Also,colNames and colModel looks like :

```
 colNames:['fname','lname'],
 colModel:[{'name:'fname', index:'fname', width:'40',editable: true,key:true},
       {name:'lname', index:'lname', width:'60', sortable:false,editable: true}]
```

OnClickSubmit shows postdata with empty values for rows i.e. postdata.fname :' ',postdata.lname:' ',though I have added values in add record pop-up.Also,the add record dialog shows values in the text filled with previous values ,that were used when adding the record first time.Please help as I am really stuck up on this issue now!

Thanks,

Shweta

Answer (score 1):

This issue was addressed in the [jqGrid forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/local-form-editing-using-jqgrid-4-6-0-version#p30642):

"The form edition[] does not support local editing. You can use inline edit for this purpose. See editurl option on how to point to local editing."

For inline editing, refer to [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing).

Comment: Please add the solution to the answer