# Closing delete dialog in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, dialog

How can I manually close it after deleting a row manually in the jqgrid (locally), no server interaction.

I delete the row using   `$('#myGrid').jqGrid('delRowData', rowId);` but the delete dialog stays open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear *why* the Delete dialog need be close manually. It it's really needed it could be done with the code like

```js
var grid_id = $.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id); // the id of the grid

$.jgrid.hideModal("#delmod" + grid, {
    gb: "#gbox_" + grid_id,
    jqm: true
});
```

Probably you try to use Delete form with local data. I described in the answer the trick with setting `processing` option to true which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800597/315935). [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847745/315935) provide the code with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing2.htm) which implement *local form editing*. The answer is small modification of [the more old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611519/315935) which did the same with more old version of jqGrid. Probably the old answers referenced above will be helpful for you.

Comment: Yes, local data. Thanks - I found your answer after I posted. When deleting local data the dialog does not close automatically.