# jqgrid How to make a delete column with a delete button for each row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I has a jqgrid and I need a delete column where each row has a delete button, but the problem is that I need to delete the row only on localdata because I don't need to go to the server but I did not know how to do this on local data only?

Comment: It's important to know **which version of jqGrid you use?** Local form editing (and local delete form) are included in jqGrid 4.7. It's possible to implement local delete in old version of jqGrid, but the code will be longer.

Comment: hola, tengo la versión jqGrid 4.5.1, pero puedo usar una versión más reciente if that is better

Comment: hi, I has the  jqGrid 4.5.1, version, but I can use a newer version if that is better, please I would like how to do local delete form in gqgrid 4.7?

Comment: I wrote in my answer that the usage of `editurl: "clientArray"` parameter of jqGrid would be enough for implementing local delete in jqGrid 4.7 or higher or for free jqGrid.

Comment: hi tony, thanks for the response, that works, I have another question, I have lines of the invoice in the jqgrid and I need to sum the total column when the user add or delete lines, Is there any method or event to do this sum?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800597/315935) where I described an implementation of local delete at the first time. The later answers: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611519/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847745/315935) contained the code for more recent version of jqGrid and for other parts of form editing.

Staring with jqGrid 4.7 one need do nothing. The usage of `editurl: "clientArray"` is the only which one need to do.

To implement "Delete" button in every row of the grid you can use `formatter: "actions"` in an additional column. By default it adds Edit and Delete buttons using `editbutton: false` in `formatoptions` of the column you can remove Edit button. In the way you will have only Delete button like you want. `delOptions` property of `formatoptions` allows you to customize the options of `delGridRow` called on click on the Delete button.

The version 4.5.1 is really old. So I recommend you to consider to upgrade to more recent version of free jqGrid which you can download from [github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Additionally with possibility of local editing/deleting you will get some performance improvements and many new features. See [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wik](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)i for more details. Some from the demos included at the end of readme uses local editing with respect of `formatter: "actions"`. So you can reduce the demos to your requirements.

Comment: hi tony, thanks for the response, that works, I hava another question, I have a lines of the invoice in the jqgrid and I need to sum the total column when the user add or delete lines, Is there any method or event to do this sum?

Comment: I am making the sum after add a new line, but the problem for me is after delete a line because there is not a event for this, so I try to delete the line from my own button out the grid, but the problem is that I dont have way to get the event onclick when the user do click on the button of the message 'Delete selected record(s)?', how I can get a event to deduct the total after the user delete the line?

Comment: @Wilmer: My name is **Oleg**, not Tony. The best way to calculate the sum by column depend on other options of jqGrid which you use. You can start with the usage of method [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) with the corresponding parameters. You can use callbacks of [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) like `afterComplete` to do some actions after the row is deleted. You should start to post the code which you use. It simplify understanding what you do and I can answer you more exactly.

Comment: thanks Oleg, I just put my code in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709294/jqgrid-what-is-the-best-way-to-sum-the-values-of-a-specific-column.