# how to save result from number input type in jqgrid form editing

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid has input type=number column defined as

```
{
    name: "amount", width: 62, template: "number",
    formatter: "number", formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 4, defaultValue: '0.0000' },
    editoptions: {
        maxlength: 4,
        type: "number",
        max: "9999"
    }
},
```

If this column in changed in form editing, changed value is not saved.
Also, it is possible to enter from keyboard value more than 9999.

To reproduce, open code below (modified from [Adding new row to jqGrid using modal form on client only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611065/adding-new-row-to-jqgrid-using-modal-form-on-client-only) answer) in Chrome.

Select row, press edit button and change amount column.
Press save button.
Changed amount does not appear in grid.

Also amount greater that 9999 can entered from keyboard.
how to fix this ? In real application data is saved to server using json format. In this case there are same issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/q/19836676/315935</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.7.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.7.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.7.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        /*global $ */
        /*jslint plusplus: true, browser: true, eqeq: true */
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    {id: "10",  invdate: "2013-11-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00"},
                    {id: "20",  invdate: "2013-11-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00"},
                    {id: "30",  invdate: "2013-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00"},
                    {id: "40",  invdate: "2013-11-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00"},
                    {id: "50",  invdate: "2013-11-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00"},
                    {id: "60",  invdate: "2013-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00"},
                    {id: "70",  invdate: "2013-11-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00"},
                    {id: "80",  invdate: "2013-11-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00"},
                    {id: "90",  invdate: "2013-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00"},
                    {id: "100", invdate: "2013-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00"},
                    {id: "110", invdate: "2013-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00"},
                    {id: "120", invdate: "2013-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00"}
                ],
                editSettings = {
                    checkOnUpdate: true,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    savekey: [true, 13],
                    closeAfterEdit: true
                },
                addSettings = {
                    checkOnUpdate: true,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                    savekey: [true, 13],
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    closeAfterAdd: true
                },
                delSettings = {
                    onclickSubmit: function () {
                        var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), newPage = p.page;

                        if (p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
                            if (p.reccount === 1 && newPage === p.lastpage) {
                                // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
                                // which is the last page of the grid
                                newPage--; // go to the previous page
                            }
                            // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: newPage}]);
                            }, 50);
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                },
                initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                            showOn: "button",
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            showWeek: true
                        });
                    }, 50);
                },
                initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            showWeek: true
                        });
                    }, 50);
                },
                removeTheOptionAll = function (elem) {
                    // We use "value" in the searchoption property of some columns of the colModel.
                    // The option {"": "All"} neams "No filter" and should be displayed only
                    // in the searching toolbar and not in the searching dialog.
                    // So we use dataInit:removeTheOptionAll inside of searchoptions to remove
                    // the option {"": "All"} in case of the searching dialog
                    if (elem != null && typeof elem.id === "string" && elem.id.substr(0, 3) !== "gs_") {
                        // we are NOT in the searching bar
                        $(elem).find("option[value=\"\"]").remove(); // remove "All" option
                    }
                };

            $("#list").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
                colModel: [
                    {name: "name", width: 60, editrules: {required: true}},
                    {name: "invdate", width: 80, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                        formatter: "date", formatoptions: {newformat: "d-M-Y", reformatAfterEdit: true},
                        editoptions: {dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14},
                        searchoptions: {dataInit: initDateSearch}},


                                    {
                                        name: "amount", width: 62, template: "number",
                                        formatter: "number", formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 4, defaultValue: '0.0000' },
                                        editoptions: {
                                            maxlength: 4,
                                            type: "number",
                                            max: "9999"
                                        }
                                    },


                    //{ name: "amount", width: 70, formatter: "number", align: "right" },



                    { name: "tax", width: 50, formatter: "number", align: "right" },
                    {name: "total", width: 60, formatter: "number", align: "right"},
                    {name: "closed", width: 70, align: "center", formatter: "checkbox",
                        edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"},
                        stype: "select",
                        searchoptions: {
                            sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
                            value: ":All;true:Yes;false:No",
                            dataInit: removeTheOptionAll
                        }},
                    {name: "ship_via", width: 100, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                        edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "TN"},
                        stype: "select",
                        searchoptions: {
                            sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
                            value: ":All;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim",
                            dataInit: removeTheOptionAll
                        }},
                    {name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, edittype: "textarea"}
                ],
                cmTemplate: {editable: true, searchoptions: {clearSearch: false }},
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                pager: "#pager",
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                sortname: "invdate",
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "Demonstrates implementating of local form editing",
                height: "100%",
                editurl: "clientArray",
                ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                    var $this = $(this), selRowId = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                    if (selRowId !== rowid) {
                        // prevent the row from be unselected on double-click
                        // the implementation is for "multiselect:false" which we use,
                        // but one can easy modify the code for "multiselect:true"
                        $this.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid);
                    }
                    $this.jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid, editSettings);
                }
            }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {}, editSettings, addSettings, delSettings, {
                multipleSearch: true,
                overlay: false,
                onClose: function () {
                    // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
                    // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
                    // the div used by datepicker
                    $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
                }
            }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn" });
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo use old jqGrid 4.7.0. Moreover you use some incorrect properties of `amount` column:

- `defaultValue: '0.0000'` is wrong in case of usage `decimalSeparator: ","`
- `maxlength: 4` is wrong in case of usage the values like `200.0000`, which have 8 characters.

Nevertheless form editing don't allow to use `type` other as from the list of supported values. I posted just now [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/7fc02e5bfe77a93103dac3ff51b1661586cb84db) to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) on GitHub. You can try with the latest sources of free jqGrid. It works now.

Comment: Thank you. This allows to save values. It still allows to enter numbers having more that maxlength digits or whose values are more than specified in max attribute.

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! `maxlength` restrict the total number of characters not digits. `type="number"` don't help you here.

Comment: I tried todays jqgrid from github. It does not encode ' character if posted from inline edit and this causes MVC application crash.  I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858311/how-to-fix-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-clie How to fix ?