# How to remove the shadow after delete the row in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

How to remove the shadow after deleting a row,

I have referred the code from [this link](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm).

After deleting the row and receiving a confirmation prompt, I reload the full div, the only problem is the shadow(white color blur background color).

I have used the code codes to remove the shadow. Its working initially, but when I tried to delete another row its not showing the delete confirmation prompt.

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").hide();
$(".ui-widget-overlay").remove();
$(".ui-widget-overlay").css("opacity","0.0");
```

see below image  [image]

Comment: please share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement.

Comment: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm the link is working code, please find it, If you need more code to i will add....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use very old demo which uses `$("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();`. Replacing the call of `.hide()` to the call of `$.jgrid.hideModal` will solves the problem (see [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3__.htm)). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800597/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296186/315935) or [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611519/315935)