# Add new row and sort in jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid

I have a grid which has date picker control and text columns. I m able to add data using modal dialog and save it to the grid and pass the same to for save/edit purpose to my server side code.

Problem:

I m how ever not sure how to sort the records those are added in the client side. I have seen one sample in which there is inline editing and sorting as shown [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortingDuringInlineOrCellEditing.htm). Though i have not seen anything which deals with adding a new row and sorting the saved data in client side.

I have used loadonce:true

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611065/adding-new-row-to-jqgrid-using-modal-form-on-client-only) approach to add records and edit records on client side as mentioned by Oleg.

Comment: Simplest would be, after adding record reload the grid with ur sorting column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nick. I dont want the added record in sorted order. My requirement is to sort the grid as a whole after i have added the record to the grid in client side. Sorry, my bad i wasnt clear with my question