# jqGrid - how to delete row from local data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, local

I am really new to the jqGrid. I'm loading local file (I'm parsing csv file into json and then transfer the array to jqGrid). Table generated through jqGrid should allow user to modify, add and delete the data in the grid. I tried to resolve my problem using various answers from here like:

[Adding new row to jqGrid using modal form on client only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611065/adding-new-row-to-jqgrid-using-modal-form-on-client-only/5611519#5611519)

There I have found the example made by Oleg for the [4.7 version of jqGrid](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing47.htm) and reproduced the same code for my purpose. The result was that I am **able** to delete row which I added after the grid initialisation but I am **unable** to delete any other row which was loaded from the array.

Another interesting thing is that I am able to modify the rows loaded from array, the only thing I cannot do with the grid is to delete rows loaded from array. I appreciate any advices.

Here is part of the code with jqGrid:

```
var delSettings = {
onclickSubmit: function () {
  var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), newPage = p.page;

    if (p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
      if (p.reccount === 1 && newPage === p.lastpage) {
        // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
        // which is the last page of the grid
        newPage--; // go to the previous page
      }
      // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
      setTimeout(function () {
        $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: newPage}]);
      }, 50);
    }
    return true;
}
};

  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: results.data,
    editurl: "clientArray",
    colModel: [
    { 
      label: 'Id',
      name: 'Id', 
      width: 60,
      editable: true, 
      key: true,
      sorttype: 'number'
    },
    { 
      label: 'Company', 
      name: 'Company', 
      width: 90,
      editoptions: {size: 40},
      editable: true,
      sorttype: 'string'
    },
    {
      label: 'Address', 
      name: 'Address', 
      width: 100,
      editoptions: {size: 40},
      editable: true
    },
    {
      label: 'City', 
      name: 'City', 
      width: 80,
      editoptions: {size: 40},
      editable: true
    }
    ],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Baza klientów Klimatest",
    pager: "#jqGridPager",
    sortable: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    cmTemplate: {editable: true, searchoptions: {clearSearch: true }},
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
  });

  // toolbar searching
  $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { defaultSearch: 'cn'});
  $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navGrid',"#jqGridPager",
  { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true, view: true},
  // options for the Edit Dialog
  {
    editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
    recreateForm: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
      return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
    }
  },
  // options for the Add Dialog
  {
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    recreateForm: true,
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
      return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
    }
  },
  // options for the Delete Dialog
  delSettings,
  // options for the Search Dialog
  {

  },
  // options for the View Dialog
  {

  });
  // add first custom button
  $('#jqGrid').navButtonAdd('#jqGridPager',
  {
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
    title: "Column chooser",
    caption: "Columns",
    position: "last",
    onClickButton: function() {
        // call the column chooser method
        jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('columnChooser');
    }
  });
```

**EDIT**
Data source is the result of parsed CSV file via Papaparse.js plugin (array of objects), which looks like this:

```
Id: "100,1"
Address: "Strefowa 8"
Company: "DSSE Sp. z o.o."
City: "Warsaw"
```

I edited the code just like Oleg suggested and I'm still able to delete only records which are added via interface of jqGrid.

I don't know if it may help, but when I click delete icon and confirm that I want to delete selected row, that row is no longer highlighted, but still visible. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: post your code for better understanding.

Comment: i am unable to find your data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clear error in your code near `// options for the View Dialog` block. The View option should be included **after** delete and search options (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition)). So your current code don't use `delSettings` options.

I recommend you additionally to include test data in your next questions, because some problems exist only with some specific format of input data.

**UPDATED**: The problem is in the data which you use. The value for `Id` which you use contains **comma** ("100,1"). It's not allowed for jqGrid. First of all id in HTML should not use characters which have special meaning in CSS. The second problem: `delGridRow` method uses commas in separator to delete multiple rows at once. So the usage of `id="100,1"` will follows to attempt to delete **tow rows**: one row with id=100 and the second one with the id=1. By the way I'm developing now jqGrid in [my fork](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid) of GitHub. I fixed many restrictions with the usage of special characters in ids. So you will be do able to use id="100,1" and successfully delete the rows if you would use jqGrid from my fork.

I recommend you to use underscore if you need to construct id which consist from multiple numbers: `Id: "100_1"` instead of `Id: "100,1"`.

Comment: I've edited the question, providing a little bit more informations.

Comment: @rascal90: See **UPDATED** part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything! I'll check your fork of the jqGrid as well.

Comment: @rascal90: You are welcome! Please post my compatibility issues if you any will find during using of jqGrid from my fork.

Comment: I tried your fork of jqGrid and resolved my problem partially. I was able to delete only 1 row of the grid, then deleting doesnt seem to work at all. I am using the same variable for **delSettings**. Normally I would use underscore for my Id column, but that Id is made like this by someone else and I have to keep it that way. Where should I put a code to show you how does it look right now? PS. When I hide the Id column deleting works like a charm (using your fork).

Comment: @rascal90: Thank you for the feedback. I made some other changes in my repository which was the reason of the problem with deleting of rows. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/delRowsWithIdsHavingComma.htm) which has very simple code and which uses the latest code. It seems to work without problems.

Comment: @rascal90: Moreover it's not really important which id values have the items in `results.data`. You can modify the data *only for jqGrid*. It you need to use unmodified `results.data` somewhere else then you can make *the copy* of `results.data` (by usage var `gridData = $.extend(true, [], results.data);`) and then modify `id` of every item by replacing `,` to `_`. The data modified in the way you can use as the input of jqGrid (`data: gridData`).

Comment: Tried with the newest demo - works like a charm for me! Thank you very much! Thank you for the advice about making a copy of the array for the grid - I'll keep that in mind for sure. I've got few more questions about jqGrid but I'll make separate questions for them. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you look on that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298703/jqgrid-jpg1-instead-of-proper-id-number
Thanks in advance!